# Convenient way to pop up context menu for each row in qtable in Quasar

Tags: vuejs3, quasar-framework, quasar

I am new to Quasar.

I know I can use the `@row-contextmenu` event of `q-table` to notify that a row has been long pressed (in mobile mode) or right clicked (in desktop mode).

But how can I pop up my context menu in the right place? I tried the `v-model` directive for `q-menu` to handle it. But there are two problems.

1. the menu popup is offset.
2. both the browser's right click menu and my menu pop up.

The code is as follows.

```html
<template>
  <q-page class="row items-center justify-evenly tiny-align">
    <q-menu touch-position v-model="showRowMenu">
      <q-list dense>
        <q-item v-close-popup>
          <q-item-section>Open...</q-item-section>
        </q-item>
        <q-separator />
        <q-item clickable v-close-popup>
          <q-item-section>New</q-item-section>
        </q-item>
      </q-list>
    </q-menu>
    <q-table
      class="full-width"
      :rows="rows"
      row-key="id"
      @row-contextmenu="popRowMenu"
    >
    </q-table>
  </q-page>
</template>
```

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue';

class Student {
  constructor(id: number, name: string) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
  }
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

const showRowMenu = ref(false);
const rows = ref<Array<Student>>([
  { id: 1, name: 'Aaron' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Bob' },
]);

function popRowMenu(evt: Event, _: Student, index: number) {
  showRowMenu.value = true;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `cell slot`.

https://codepen.io/Pratik__007/pen/RwMRyNy